# Hazrat Umar and bibi Fatima incident

Tags: sunni, shiism, shia-sunni

What's the Sunni take on/perspective on incident of Hazrat Umar and bibi Fatima when he charged her during her pregnancy?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Fatima had more than one pregnancy be specific add all necessara infromatiom as is at least to me it is unclear what incident you are talking about. (see [ask]). And cosnider taking the [tour] and visiting the [help] to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: See [Umar at Fatimah's house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umar_at_Fatimah%27s_house). Look under the 'event' section.

Answer (score 2):

Sunnis consider the "incident" to be fabricated with the intention to slander Abu Bakr and Umar.

In Shia books which claim this incident, it is not recorded with a sound chain of narrators, so Sunnis do not accept it.

The oldest reference to this incident is the Shia book called **Al-Saqifa** (السقيفة) or **Kitab Sulaym bin Qais** ( كتاب سليم بن قيس ) which is a collection of narrations attributed to **Sulaym bin Qays**
(سليم بن قيس الهلالي) and collected by **Aban ibn abi-Ayyash** (أبان بن أبي عياش فيروز) who is **weak** (ضعيف)  and his book is **fabricated** (موضوع) according to Sunnis and also several Shia works on Ilm al Rijal such  [كتاب الرجال](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/2941_%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_0?pageno=249#top)  of  ابن داوود الحلي :

> ٢ ـ أبان بن أبي عياش ، بالياء المثناة تحت والشين المعجمة  فيروزين ( جخ
>   غض ) **ضعيف** ، قيل إنه وضع كتاب سليم بن قيس
>
> ٢٢٦ ـ سليم بن قيس الهلالي ى ، ن ، سين ، ين ( جخ ) ينسب إليه الكتاب
>   المشهور وهو **موضوع** بدليل أنه قال : إن محمد بن أبي بكر وعظ أباه عند
>   موته. وقال فيه : إن الائمة ثلاثة عشر مع زيد. وأسانيده مختلفة ( غض ) :
>   لم يرو عنه إلا أبان بن أبي عياش وفي الكتاب **مناكير** مشتهرة ، وما أظنه
>   إلا **موضوعا**

The same is in  [تصحيح اعتقادات الإمامية page 149](http://ar.lib.eshia.ir/15141/1/149) and [جامع الرواة page 9](http://ar.lib.eshia.ir/14021/1/9) etc.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking the [Tour] and checking our [help] to make yourself familiar with our site and model. A quote with the content of this hadith would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Sunnis believe that this is a lie spun to degrade the Ahle Bait and to malign the Sahaba.

Ali, the Lion of Allah, whose bravery and strength is unmatched, would never have let such a thing happen on his watch. And if it had happened, Ali would never have pledged allegiance to Abu Bakr and Umar, and he would have taken swift revenge from them.

Instead Ali gave allegiance to both, and he said the following about Umar on his deathbed:

> Narrated Ibn Abbas:
>
> When (the dead body of) Umar was put on his deathbed, the people
>   gathered around him and invoked (Allah) and prayed for him before the
>   body was taken away, and I was amongst them. Suddenly I felt somebody
>   taking hold of my shoulder and found out that he was Ali bin Abi
>   Talib.
>
> Ali invoked Allah's Mercy for Umar and said, "**O Umar! You have not
>   left behind you a person whose deeds I like to imitate and meet Allah
>   with more than I like your deeds.** By Allah! I always thought that
>   Allah would keep you with your two companions, for very often I used
>   to hear the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, 'I, Abu Bakr and Umar went
>   (somewhere); I, Abu Bakr and Umar entered (somewhere); and I, Abu
>   Bakr and Umar went out."'

Muttafaq alaih [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/62/35) wa [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/18)

Comment: I do agree that this alleged lie would degrade the Sahaba, but don't understand how would it degrade the Ahle Bait? Can you elaborate?